# How can I copy one attribute from one class to another?

Tags: c#

```
class person
{
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the FirstName of person")]
string FirstName{get; set ;}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the LastName of person")]
string LastName{get; set ;}
}

class Student
{
string FirstName{get; set ;}
string LastName{get; set ;}
}

Person p = new Person();
Student s = new Student();
```

I want to copy the attributes from `person` to `Student`;
How can it?

Comment: Are those properties private?

Answer (score 4):

You could use inheritance to make this easier.

```
class Student : Person
{

}
```

Comment: This is the 'right' OO way of doing this, but note that the attributes will only be 'copied' if the `RequiredAttribute` class is flagged as inherited: `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]`. If it isn't then `Student` will inherit the properties from `Person` but not their `[Required]` attributes.

Comment: @Keith `RequiredAttribute` has that.

Comment: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` does, `Microsoft.Build.Framework.RequiredAttribute` does not, and `RequiredAttribute` could be their own custom one too. While I think the first is the most likely I still think the clarification is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "attribute", you actually mean "property"...

There's no "automatic" way to do it, you need to copy the values manually.

```
Person p = ...
Student s = new Student { FirstName  = p.FirstName, LastName = p.LastName };
```

Depending on the context, you could also use an object mapper like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Comment: The OP did say copy "from one class to another". Do you think they meant "instance" instead of "class"? And as the properties are private, you can't simply copy them from the outside, because you don't have access. I don't think your reply answers the question at all.

Comment: @MrLister, I don't think the OP posted his actual code. It wouldn't make sense to make such properties private. Anyway, that's how I understood the question, which wasn't exactly clear... but I might be wrong.

Comment: I may be wrong, in which case, sorry. But if you need to assume that the OP means "property" instead of "attribute", AND "instance" instead of "class", AND that the properties are actually public, AND that with all your assumptions, the question becomes horribly simplistic, then I think he means it the way he says it. Besides, the example _does_ have attributes in it...

Answer (score 0):

If `Student` inherits `Person`, it will both have the properties, and both their attributes.

```
class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the FirstName of person")]
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the LastName of person")]
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection like this :

```
foreach (var getter in s.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var newData = getter.GetValue(newProject, null);
    var setter = p.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)
    setter.SetValue(p, newData, null);
}
```

Comment: That will copy the values of the properties, but do nothing about their attributes.

Comment: I figured that's what he wanted.(His question wasn't that elaborate)